# Rust cache async traits

Tags: concurrency, rust, async-await, parallel-processing, trait-objects

I'm running into an issue when I attempt to cache a value for as long as it's valid and update it when it becomes invalid.  I believe the issue is due to my attempt to share state across async executions.  Further, this component lives in a multi-threaded / concurrent environment.

The error I'm seeing that I don't know how to fix is

```
future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
```

Following is a minimum example that I could come up with (it also features some ownership issues) that generally captures my use-case and the issue I'm seeing.  [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=391601baea0aa5024542d2040adbab8e) is a playground of the code.

```rust
use async_trait::async_trait;
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct Creds {
    expires_at: DateTime<Utc>,
}

impl Creds {
    fn is_expired(&self) -> bool {
        self.expires_at.le(&Utc::now())
    }
}

#[async_trait]
trait CredsProvider {
    async fn get_creds(&self) -> Creds;
}

struct MyCredsProvider {
    cached_creds: Arc<Mutex<Option<Creds>>>,
}

impl MyCredsProvider {
    fn new() -> Self {
        MyCredsProvider {
            cached_creds: Arc::new(Mutex::new(None)),
        }
    }
    async fn inner_get_creds(&self) -> Creds {
        todo!()
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl CredsProvider for MyCredsProvider {
    async fn get_creds(&self) -> Creds {
        let mg = self
            .cached_creds
            .lock()
            .expect("Unable to get lock on creds mutex");
        if mg.is_some() && !mg.as_ref().unwrap().is_expired() {
            return mg.unwrap();
        }
        let new_creds = self.inner_get_creds().await;
        *mg = Some(new_creds);
        return new_creds;
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    MyCredsProvider::new();
    // Some multi-threaded / concurrent logic to periodically refresh creds
    todo!()
}
```

I wasn't sure how to include this in the example but in `main` imagine multiple worker threads running concurrently / parallel that each call `CredsProvider.get_creds` and then use these creds to perform some work (if you can add that to a complete working example, that'd be much appreciated for my edification).  Assume `MyCredsProvider.inner_get_creds` is expensive and should only be called when the cached creds expire.

How do I solve this?  I thought that the `Arc<Mutex<>>` would be enough but it seems not.  At one point, I tried making `Creds` and trait so that I could have `Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<dyn Creds + Send + Sync>>>>` but that felt like the wrong path and didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may would like to switch to [tokio::sync::Mutex](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.4/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html) ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=946b264ed45151017cb5545160b9e7c3)).

It solves

```
future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
```

Code:

```
use async_trait::async_trait;
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::Mutex;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Creds {
    expires_at: DateTime<Utc>,
}

impl Creds {
    fn is_expired(&self) -> bool {
        self.expires_at.le(&Utc::now())
    }
}

#[async_trait]
trait CredsProvider {
    async fn get_creds(&self) -> Creds;
}

struct MyCredsProvider {
    cached_creds: Arc<Mutex<Option<Creds>>>,
}

impl MyCredsProvider {
    fn new() -> Self {
        MyCredsProvider {
            cached_creds: Arc::new(Mutex::new(None)),
        }
    }
    async fn inner_get_creds(&self) -> Creds {
        todo!()
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl CredsProvider for MyCredsProvider {
    async fn get_creds(&self) -> Creds {
        let mut mg = self
            .cached_creds
            .lock()
            .await;
        if mg.is_some() && !mg.as_ref().unwrap().is_expired() {
            return mg.clone().unwrap();
        } else {
            let new_creds = self.inner_get_creds().await;
            *mg = Some(new_creds.clone());
            return new_creds;
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    MyCredsProvider::new();
    // Some multi-threaded / concurrent logic to periodically refresh creds
    todo!()
}
```